# Issue looping a trial to an accuracy criterion in JsPsych - continues looping infinitely

Tags: javascript, jspsych

I'm very new to using JsPsych and I'm trying to create a very simple math quiz task as practice. I intend to have random math questions as the prompt, and then after 10 correct answers, the task should end. I have made code that successfully selects random math problems from a list and successfully loops. I am unsure exactly where the error is, but it could be

1. where I define correct answers
2. where I count correct answers
3. where I loop the questions

My code is below, please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thank you in advance! Edit: I'm adding another attempt with different code but same issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> <!-- all preloads go into head -->
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
    <!-- any plugins go here-->
    <script src="jspsych/dist/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script src = "jspsych/dist/plugin-survey-text.js"></script>
    <link href="jspsych/dist/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body> <!-- all script for tasks go into body-->
    <script> 
    
    var jsPsych = initJsPsych();

    var timeline = [];

// create a randomly selected math problem prompt and define correct answer
var test = {
    type: jsPsychSurveyText,
    questions: [
        {
            prompt: function() {
                var MathQuest = [

                '2+2', '3+7', 'How many weeks in a year?'

                ];

                var mathProblems = jsPsych.randomization.sampleWithReplacement(MathQuest, 1)[0];
                return mathProblems;
            },
            name: 'resp',
        }
    ],
    post_trial_gap: 500,
    on_finish: function(data) {
        var correctResponses = {

        '2+2' : '4',
        '3+7' : '10',
        'How many weeks in a year?' : '52'
        };

        var response = data.response;

        if (correctResponses[data.prompt] === response) {

            data.correct = true;

        } else {

            data.correct = false;

        }
    }
}; // end test trial

 // Create a loop node for the test with accuracy criteria:
 var correctCount = 0; // Counter for correct responses

      var loopNode = {
        timeline: [test],
        loop_function: function(data) {
          // Check if the loop should continue based on the number of correct responses
          if (correctCount < 10) {
            if (data.values()[0].correct) {
              correctCount++;
            }
            return true; // Continue the loop
          } else {
            return false; // End the loop
          }
          console.log("Correct Count: " + correctCount);
        },
      };

    jsPsych.run([loopNode]);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2nd attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> <!-- all preloads go into head -->
    <title>Math Quiz Take 2</title>
    <!-- any plugins go here-->
    <script src="jspsych/dist/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script src = "jspsych/dist/plugin-survey-text.js"></script>
    <link href="jspsych/dist/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body> <!-- all script for tasks go into body-->
    <script> 

var jsPsych = initJsPsych();

var timeline = [];

var mathQuestions = [
  {math: '2+2 = ?', correct: '4'},
  {math: '2x3 = ?', correct: '6'},
  {math: '5x7 = ?', correct: '35'}
];

var test = {
  type: jsPsychSurveyText,
  questions: [
    {
      prompt: jsPsych.timelineVariable('math'), 
      name: 'resp'
    }
  ],
        on_finish: function(data) {
                  data.correct=jsPsych.timelineVariable('correct');
                  var acc = 0;
                  var response = data.response.resp;
            if (response == data.correct){
                acc++;
            }
          }
};

var mathQuestionProcedure = {
  timeline: [test],
  timeline_variables: mathQuestions,
  loop_function: function(data) {
    if (acc < 2) {
            return true; //go to criteria
        } else {
            return false; //end loop
        }
  }
}
timeline.push(mathQuestionProcedure);

jsPsych.run([mathQuestionProcedure])

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second attempt looks closer to me. I think the problem is that you initialized `var acc = 0` inside the `on_finish` function, so it is scoped to that function. If you add `var acc = 0` before you create the `test` object and remove it from the function, that will make it a global variable and might fix the problem.